# Dirac conjugation of a 3x3 matrix

Tags: dirac-matrices

This question might be stupid, but when I compute $\bar{B}$ in the Lagrangian, I have to multiply 3x3 $B$ matrix with 4x4 $\gamma_0$ matrix (Dirac's conjugation) which are incompatible in size. What is wrong here? Is it because of the Trace being taken? (Sp = spur = trace)

[image: ]]

Comment: Do you mind if you also included a reference for the paper/book/article where you've taken this from?

Answer (score 1):

The conjugation is done element by element. The matrix $B$ is in the fundamental representation of $SU(3)$ but each of its elements is a [baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon) (hyperon) and as such, it is a dirac fermion, *i.e.* in the spin $\frac{1}{2}$ representation of the Lorentz group. So what is meant by the conjugate of $B$ is actually the conjugate of its elements, which are 4 dimensional vectors (dirac spinors) and would transform appropriately.